# When $f\left(\|Ax\|\right)\leq \|f(A)x\|$ is true?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, matrix-analysis

When is the following relation true?

$$f\left(\|Ax\|\right)\leq \|f(A)x\|$$  where $A$ is any matrix and $\|\cdot\|$ is the spectral norm.

Edit note :

The function $$ is any real concave increasing value function on $[0,∞)$

Comment: What's $f$ here? Are you using the continuous functional calculus?

Comment: The answer is: depends what you mean by $f$ here. Note that the function on the LHS and the function on the RHS live on disjoint sets, which means you can define a lot of functions satisfying or not satisfying the relation.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write that $f$ is any real concave increasing value function on $[0,\infty)$

Comment: What does $f(A)$ mean then?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are looking for. In general, the answer is "very rarely". For instance take $f(t)=t^2$. Then you are asking for 
$$\tag1
\|Ax\|^2\leq\|A^2x\|. 
$$
This has obvious problems in that it doesn't scale well: suppose you had equality for $x$: then then inequality would fail for $2x$. Also, if $A$ is nilpotent of order two ($A^2=0$) then the right-hand-side is zero while the left-hand-side will be nonzero for certain $x$.

The scaling problems guarantee that even for positive definite $A$ the inequality $(1)$ has problems: for instance if $A$ is a projection, the inequality becomes $\|Ax\|^2\leq \|Ax\|$, so if $Ax\ne0$ you get $\|Ax\|\leq1$, again with obvious scaling problems.

If $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, even with positive definite $A$ you still run into problems: take $A$ to be a projection, then you want
$$
\|Ax\|^{1/2}\leq\|Ax\|,
$$
which is the same (when $Ax\ne0$) to $\|Ax\|\geq1$. So again you have to look at specific $x$ and your inequality doesn't scale.

Comment: ok what about if   is any real concave increasing value function on [0,∞) which I forgot to write in the question. Thanks

Comment: I included another example with $f(t)=t^{1/2}$.